# Format Google Chart Table columns using abbreviated words

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Can this be done?

So if i have a value of 1000000, i would like to be able to format the date as either 1m or 1million.

The exact functionality is available on the axis of charts, which can be found below, but no mention of how to do it in a table column

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Visualization API does provide a set of [formatters](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters), specifically for formatting data.
Including...

> ArrowFormat
>   BarFormat
>   ColorFormat
>   DateFormat
>   NumberFormat
>   PatternFormat

Following is an example of using the [NumberFormat](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat)...

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  // adapted from previous example
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [['id', 'amt'],[1,1100244543243.223],[2,123034345431.2334],[3,213065432.23411],[4,1140.34231342342314],[5,360.454343343223],[6,50.5434221],[7,9.54324324314],[8,0.45324517]]
  );

  // format numbers in second column
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    prefix: '$',
    pattern: 'short'
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  // draw chart
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, {});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, should of tried passing in "short" into the pattern. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Is is possible?** yes it is.
how? you can create your own formatter
Here is a snippet to get you started.It isn't a full solution but you can do something similar

```
var NumberFormatter = function (number) {
    this.number = number;

    this.short = function(){
        var shortDescription = '';
        if (this.number%100000 == 0) {
            shortDescription = (this.number/100000) + 'M'
            return shortDescription;
        }
        return this.number;
    }
    return this;
}

console.log(new NumberFormatter(1800000).short());
//Sample output
18M
```